ClassNotFoundError: Attempted to load class "Builder" from namespace "Endroid\QrCode\Builder"
I am developing a plugin for Shopware 6 and I need this QR code library for it. My problem is that when I try to get the library running, I keep getting the aforementioned error messages.
The namespaces are all correct, everything is installed via Composer and is ready. My example is exactly the same as the one on Packagist, yet I still get this error.
use Endroid\QrCode\Builder\Builder;
use Endroid\QrCode\Encoding\Encoding;
use Endroid\QrCode\ErrorCorrectionLevel;
use Endroid\QrCode\Label\LabelAlignment;
use Endroid\QrCode\Label\Font\NotoSans;
use Endroid\QrCode\RoundBlockSizeMode;
use Endroid\QrCode\Writer\PngWriter;

$result = Builder::create()
    ->writer(new PngWriter())
    ->writerOptions([])
    ->data('Custom QR code contents')
    ->encoding(new Encoding('UTF-8'))
    ->errorCorrectionLevel(ErrorCorrectionLevel::High)
    ->size(300)
    ->margin(10)
    ->roundBlockSizeMode(RoundBlockSizeMode::Margin)
    ->logoPath(__DIR__.'/assets/symfony.png')
    ->logoResizeToWidth(50)
    ->logoPunchoutBackground(true)
    ->labelText('This is the label')
    ->labelFont(new NotoSans(20))
    ->labelAlignment(LabelAlignment::Center)
    ->validateResult(false)
    ->build();

I also tried to implement it with another library (bacon/bacon-qr-code) and it was also complaining about the same issue but only a different namespace ImageRenderer
What could the problem be? I am using Docker (v4.34.4), Symfony (v6.6.6.1) and PHP (v8.3)
EDIT 13.10.2024
www-data@741042a1609d:~/html$ php bin/console cache:clear

 // Clearing the cache for the dev environment with debug true                                                          

 // Warming up cache...                                                                                                 

 // Warming up optional cache...                                                                                        

 // Removing old build and cache directory...                                                                           

 // Finished                                                                                                            

                                                                                                                        
 [OK] Cache for the "dev" environment (debug=true) was successfully cleared.                                            
                                                                                                                        

www-data@741042a1609d:~/html$ cd custom/plugins/ShrQrProGen/
www-data@741042a1609d:~/html/custom/plugins/ShrQrProGen$ composer dump-autoload -o
Deprecation Notice: Using ${var} in strings is deprecated, use {$var} instead in phar:///usr/local/bin/composer/src/Composer/Autoload/AutoloadGenerator.php:879
Deprecation Notice: Using ${var} in strings is deprecated, use {$var} instead in phar:///usr/local/bin/composer/src/Composer/Autoload/AutoloadGenerator.php:884
Generating optimized autoload files
Generated optimized autoload files containing 9983 classes
www-data@741042a1609d:~/html/custom/plugins/ShrQrProGen$ tail -f ../../../var/log/dev.log 
[2024-10-13T18:36:35.730919+00:00] app.INFO: #9 Rule detection: Alle Kunden der Standard-Kundengruppe with priority 1 (id: 28caae75a5624f0d985abd0eb32aa160) [] []
[2024-10-13T18:36:35.732180+00:00] php.INFO: User Deprecated: Since shopware/core : The tag `shopware.payment.method.sync` is deprecated for service Shopware\Core\Checkout\Payment\Cart\PaymentHandler\PrePayment and will be removed in 6.7.0. Use `shopware.payment.handler` instead. {"exception":"[object] (ErrorException(code: 0): User Deprecated: Since shopware/core : The tag `shopware.payment.method.sync` is deprecated for service Shopware\\Core\\Checkout\\Payment\\Cart\\PaymentHandler\\PrePayment and will be removed in 6.7.0. Use `shopware.payment.handler` instead. at /var/www/html/vendor/shopware/core/Checkout/Payment/Cart/PaymentHandler/PaymentHandlerRegistry.php:48)"} []
[2024-10-13T18:36:35.732326+00:00] php.INFO: User Deprecated: Since shopware/core : The tag `shopware.payment.method.sync` is deprecated for service Shopware\Core\Checkout\Payment\Cart\PaymentHandler\DebitPayment and will be removed in 6.7.0. Use `shopware.payment.handler` instead. {"exception":"[object] (ErrorException(code: 0): User Deprecated: Since shopware/core : The tag `shopware.payment.method.sync` is deprecated for service Shopware\\Core\\Checkout\\Payment\\Cart\\PaymentHandler\\DebitPayment and will be removed in 6.7.0. Use `shopware.payment.handler` instead. at /var/www/html/vendor/shopware/core/Checkout/Payment/Cart/PaymentHandler/PaymentHandlerRegistry.php:48)"} []
[2024-10-13T18:36:35.732418+00:00] php.INFO: User Deprecated: Since shopware/core : The tag `shopware.payment.method.sync` is deprecated for service Shopware\Core\Checkout\Payment\Cart\PaymentHandler\CashPayment and will be removed in 6.7.0. Use `shopware.payment.handler` instead. {"exception":"[object] (ErrorException(code: 0): User Deprecated: Since shopware/core : The tag `shopware.payment.method.sync` is deprecated for service Shopware\\Core\\Checkout\\Payment\\Cart\\PaymentHandler\\CashPayment and will be removed in 6.7.0. Use `shopware.payment.handler` instead. at /var/www/html/vendor/shopware/core/Checkout/Payment/Cart/PaymentHandler/PaymentHandlerRegistry.php:48)"} []
[2024-10-13T18:36:35.732509+00:00] php.INFO: User Deprecated: Since shopware/core : The tag `shopware.payment.method.sync` is deprecated for service Shopware\Core\Checkout\Payment\Cart\PaymentHandler\InvoicePayment and will be removed in 6.7.0. Use `shopware.payment.handler` instead. {"exception":"[object] (ErrorException(code: 0): User Deprecated: Since shopware/core : The tag `shopware.payment.method.sync` is deprecated for service Shopware\\Core\\Checkout\\Payment\\Cart\\PaymentHandler\\InvoicePayment and will be removed in 6.7.0. Use `shopware.payment.handler` instead. at /var/www/html/vendor/shopware/core/Checkout/Payment/Cart/PaymentHandler/PaymentHandlerRegistry.php:48)"} []
[2024-10-13T18:36:35.732590+00:00] php.INFO: User Deprecated: Since shopware/core : The tag `shopware.payment.method.sync` is deprecated for service Shopware\Core\Checkout\Payment\Cart\PaymentHandler\DefaultPayment and will be removed in 6.7.0. Use `shopware.payment.handler` instead. {"exception":"[object] (ErrorException(code: 0): User Deprecated: Since shopware/core : The tag `shopware.payment.method.sync` is deprecated for service Shopware\\Core\\Checkout\\Payment\\Cart\\PaymentHandler\\DefaultPayment and will be removed in 6.7.0. Use `shopware.payment.handler` instead. at /var/www/html/vendor/shopware/core/Checkout/Payment/Cart/PaymentHandler/PaymentHandlerRegistry.php:48)"} []
[2024-10-13T18:36:35.869849+00:00] php.INFO: User Deprecated: Since shopware/core : Method "Shopware\Storefront\Page\Product\ProductPage::setReviews()" is deprecated and will be removed in v6.7.0.0. {"exception":"[object] (ErrorException(code: 0): User Deprecated: Since shopware/core : Method \"Shopware\\Storefront\\Page\\Product\\ProductPage::setReviews()\" is deprecated and will be removed in v6.7.0.0. at /var/www/html/vendor/shopware/core/Framework/Feature.php:242)"} []
[2024-10-13T18:36:35.869992+00:00] php.INFO: User Deprecated: Since shopware/core : Method "Shopware\Storefront\Page\Product\ProductPage::setCrossSellings()" is deprecated and will be removed in v6.7.0.0. {"exception":"[object] (ErrorException(code: 0): User Deprecated: Since shopware/core : Method \"Shopware\\Storefront\\Page\\Product\\ProductPage::setCrossSellings()\" is deprecated and will be removed in v6.7.0.0. at /var/www/html/vendor/shopware/core/Framework/Feature.php:242)"} []
[2024-10-13T18:36:35.870170+00:00] app.INFO: QrProGenSubscriber: onProductPageLoaded [] []
[2024-10-13T18:36:36.066754+00:00] request.CRITICAL: Uncaught PHP Exception Symfony\Component\ErrorHandler\Error\ClassNotFoundError: "Attempted to load class "Builder" from namespace "Endroid\QrCode\Builder". Did you forget a "use" statement for e.g. "Lcobucci\JWT\Token\Builder" or "Lcobucci\JWT\Builder"?" at QrProGenSubscriber.php line 105 {"exception":"[object] (Symfony\\Component\\ErrorHandler\\Error\\ClassNotFoundError(code: 0): Attempted to load class \"Builder\" from namespace \"Endroid\\QrCode\\Builder\".\nDid you forget a \"use\" statement for e.g. \"Lcobucci\\JWT\\Token\\Builder\" or \"Lcobucci\\JWT\\Builder\"? at /var/www/html/custom/plugins/ShrQrProGen/src/Subscriber/QrProGenSubscriber.php:105)"} []

EDIT 14.10.2024
composer.json
{
  ..
  "require": {
    "shopware/core": "6.6.*",
    "endroid/qr-code": "^5.1"
  },
  "autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
      "Shr\\QrProGen\\": "src/"
    }
  },
  ..
}

ShrQrProGen.php
<?php declare(strict_types=1);

namespace Shr\QrProGen;

use Shopware\Core\Framework\Plugin;

class ShrQrProGen extends Plugin
{

    public function boot(): void
    {
        parent::boot();
        $autoload = $this->getPath() . '/vendor/autoload.php';
        if (file_exists($autoload)) {
            require_once $autoload;
        }
    }
}


"I need this QR code library for it" - which one is "this"? Can you share which library you try to install, and in which version?

I edited my post. I installed endroid/qr-code with the current stable version 5.1

The code you've shared doesn't include the autoloader - or do you use it in any other way?

Added my autoloader

The PHP script still does not contain any autoloader. How do you call the script?

Set the autoloader in my main class. autoload.php also exists in vendor so this approach attempts to include the vendor/autoload.php from my plugin's directory, which is correct if I want to manage dependencies locally within the plugin

Did you check whether the autoloader is really included? Did you check whether it contains the classes from that library, and whether they really exist? It should not be too hard to put a breakpoint on the boot() method to see what it does

That's very stupid. Everything exists but I was too dumb to recognised that my vendor folder is on the same level as my src folder but he was looking the vendor folder inside my src folder. Thx for guiding me the correct way

If PHP is inside a Docker container, then composer commands should also be run inside the container.
You can also try to execute commands inside the container in the root directory of the symfony project.
php bin/console cache:clear

composer dump-autoload -o


Same problem and of course I tried it within the docker container, look my edit

In this case, it is worth checking the version of the installed https://github.com/endroid/qr-code package. Perhaps it really does not have this class? Judging by https://symfonycasts.com/screencast/symfony-security/qr-code#comment-26978, different versions of this library may require different approaches.

Tried it but I got similiar error. Replaced the use-Statement with Endroid/QrCode/QrCode but no other result. Now I got Attempted to load class "QrCode" from namespace "Endroid\QrCode". Did you forget a "use" statement for another namespace?

You didn't say either the library version or the result of checking the physical existence of the file with the problematic class, without this information I have no idea how to help?(

All files are existing (Builder and QrCode) and I extended my composer.json file with the autoloader. endroid/qr-code is version 5.1
